# Ionic2 image overlay

Tags: ionic2

I need some guidance/directions/code samples for image overlays in Ionic2 app.

I am capturing image using native camera and then I want to edit the captured image by adding some text like following (this is from *Instaweather* app):

[image]

After editing I want to share this image on social media like whatsapp etc (as of now I can share the captured image without editing, which was pretty straight forward).

I have a directive as following, but it didn't help much.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[draw-text]' 
})
export class ImageDrawTextDirective {
  @Input() text: any;
  @HostListener('load', ['$event.target'])

  onLoad(img) {
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;

    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    context.font = "50px Arial";
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.fillText(this.text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height * 0.8);

    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }
}
```

Which I was using like following:

```
 <!-- Display the captured image with text on it -->
 <img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" text="{{flavour}}" draw-text crossOrigin />
```